# In Site.com why does "Site Overwrite" fail?

Tags: site.com

I've done an overwrite before, and it's worked. But now it's failing every time. I've exported the site (from a sandbox) to a `.site` file. Then I overwrite, select the file, and yet it fails. I get the "This Site is large. We'll email you when the overwrite is complete" message.

Then, the email that arrives says...

`Site Import Failed
Unfortunately, we encountered an error while importing null Error ID: 992085351-1354036 (-1092065488).`

How can I get a successful overwrite? The `.site` file is 51 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me earlier and it looks to be an ORG LOCK MESSAGE error probably because of parallel sites admin operations. Would recommend you to import the file OFF-PEAK hours.

Comment: Yes, this is it. There was a validation deploy happening on our PROD org at the same time. The org was locked, and so Site.com rewrites were not permitted.